# Помогите с парсером (simple_html_dom)

Tags: php, html

Есть список с категориями товаром. В каждом li находится еще один список с подкатегориями. Как с помощью simple_html_dom вывести категории и подкатегории? Заранее благодарен

```
//подгружаем библиотеку 
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php'; 
//создаём новый объект 
$html = new simple_html_dom(); 
//загружаем в него данные $html = file_get_html('smeg-store.com.ua/'); 
if ($html->innertext!='' and count($html->find('nav.header__cats li ul '))) { 
   foreach ($html->find('nav.header__cats li ul') as $a) { 
      # code... 
      echo $a->parent()->children(0)->innertext.'<br />'; 
      echo $a->parent()->innertext.'<br />'; } } 
//освобождаем ресурсы 
$html->clear(); 
unset($html);
```

Comment: в каком месте у вас перестало получаться? при постановке задачи? а пос=чему тогда именно simple_html_dom ?

Comment: Получается по отдельности вывести категории и подкатегории, но в моменте когда есть категория без подкатегорий не удается вывести эти категории

Comment: показывайте код, попробуем подсказать

Comment: <?php
//подгружаем библиотеку
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
//создаём новый объект
$html = new simple_html_dom();
//загружаем в него данные
$html = file_get_html('http://smeg-store.com.ua/');

if ($html->innertext!='' and count($html->find('nav.header__cats li ul ')))
{
 foreach ($html->find('nav.header__cats li ul') as $a)
 {
  # code...
  echo $a->parent()->children(0)->innertext.'<br />';
  echo $a->parent()->innertext.'<br />';
 }
}
//освобождаем ресурсы
$html->clear(); 
unset($html);
?>

Comment: первое echo выводить отдельно категории у которых есть подкатегории, второе echo выводит категории и подкатегории, не удается вывести категории у которых нет подкатегорий

Comment: нажмите "править" под вопросом и добавьте в вопрос.